# Xamarin iOS - Binding Project - Warning

Tags: ios, binding, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Am using

Xamarin Studio - 4.0.4 (build 2)
Mono - 2.10.11
Xamarin.iOS - 6.3.5.43
Mac OS X - 10.8.2

When building the wrapper binding class, I get a warning saying 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' is present in multiple assemblies. Its just a warning, but builds the .dll file.

Target GenerateBindings:

Tool /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/btouch execution started with arguments: /unsafe /d:DEBUG ApiDefinition.cs /s:StructsAndEnums.cs /tmpdir:obj/Debug/ios/ /sourceonly:obj/Debug/ios//sources.list

warning CS1685:

The predefined type `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' is defined in multiple assemblies. Using definition from`mscorlib'

/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous warning)
        /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/mono/2.0/System.Core.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous warning)

But when using the created binding class in another project, it gives the error saying
Compiling to native code -
'error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.'

In the build log 
ld: file not found: /var/folders/w4/xsz8x8vx0_51hjxj474r1_fxhlq7x3/T/tmp9aef74.tmp/libPrint.a
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Note : libPrint.a is my static library

-Update-

When binding the libPrint.a file to the wrapper class, the .a file should be added to the project and not inside the 'Resources' folder. This solved the issue am facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is because of the ambiguity for System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' in multiple assemblies.

Keeping the warning aside, the real problem is when adding libPrint.a file.
Its a small silly mistake. The [docs](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_libraries) of xamarin clearly explain it.
It should be added to the project and not inside the 'Resources' folder.
This solved the error I'm getting when using the .dll file for a project.

Answer (score 1):

Does libPrint.a support the architecture you are building your iOS project for?

IOW, if you are compiling for Simulator, your libPrint.a needs to support i386.

If you are compiling for device, it needs to support whatever ARM arch you are targeting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Yeah, the libPrint.a supports all the architectures - i386 for simulator and armv7 and armv7s

Comment: What is the rest of the build output for your bindings? Did it embed libPrint.a as a resource? (it should). What are the contents of your libPrint.linkwith.cs file? Do you have one?